# QTP: Getting the value of a checkbox

Tags: checkbox, automated-tests, qtp

I want to know that how many checkboxes are present on the home page of [www.gmail.com](http://www.gmail.com) and also I want to check the checkbox is checked or not .....

My code is....

```
Set obj= Description.Create()
obj("name").value="PersistentCookie"
obj("html tag").value="INPUT"
obj("type").value="checkbox"

Set a = Browser("name:=Gmail.*","title:=Gmail.*").Page("title:=Gmail.*").Childobjects(obj)
MsgBox a.count

c =Browser("name:=Gmail.*", "title:=Gmail.*").Page("title:=Gmail.*").GetROProperty("checked")
MsgBox c
```

The value of `c` is always "OFF" even i checked the checkbox (Remember me on this computer) and execute the above code but value of `c` is always "OFF"

Please help me on this
thanks in advance...

kindly reply on this..

Answer (score 2):

You're running the `GetROProperty` function on the Page object rather than the check-box you found (I don't know why `Page` has a `checked` property) but if you run on the test object returned by `ChildObjects` you will get the correct value (1 for `true` 0 for `false`).

```
c = a(0).GetROProperty("checked")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
c = Browser("name:=Gmail.*","title:=Gmail.*").Page("title:=Gmail.*").WebCheckBox("name:=PersistentCookie").GetROProperty("checked")
```

Add above line in your code and you will get correct result in message box, for "ON" you get `1`, for "OFF" `0`.